# Check file type using php scandir not working

Tags: php, image, file, directory

I am using this bellow php to check the the kind of file saved in database, but it show everything as folder please i don't know what the problem is.

```
<?php
$path = dirname(__FILE__);
$sub_folder = scandir($path);
$num = count($sub_folder);
//$jailchillink This is the name of file saved in database replaced width index.php
    if(is_file($path.'\\'.index.php)){  $codetype = 'file';}
   else if(is_img($path.'\\'.index.php)){  $codetype = 'image';}
    else{ $codetype = 'folder';}?>
```

The above code will output `folder`

Comment: Debug: use `echo` or `print_r` to display the contents of each variable or function call after each line of code. This way you can easily spot where the problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
  $path = dirname(__FILE__);
  $sub_folder = scandir($path);
  $num = count($sub_folder);
  //$jailchillink This is the name of file saved in database replaced  width index.php
  if(is_file($path.'\\'.'index.php')){
     echo $codetype = 'file';
  }else if(is_img($path.'\\'.'index.php')){
    echo $codetype = 'image';
  }else{ 
    echo $codetype = 'folder';
  }
?>
```

Now the output is `file`. just add `'` around `index.php`.